# Запоминать активный tab после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

На странице есть n-ное количество вкладок с заполнением:

```
<div class="section">
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="current">Вкладка 1</li>
<li>Вкладка 2</li>
<li>Вкладка 3</li>
</ul>
<div class="box visible"> //заполнение
вкладка один
<div class="box">
вкладка два
<div class="box">
вкладка три
```

JS:

```
(function($) 
{$(function() {

$('ul.tabs').delegate('li:not(.current)', 'click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current')
        .parents('div.section').find('div.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(150);
})

})
})(jQuery)
```

Соответственно, если ты выбрал вкладку 2, а потом перезагрузил страницу активной снова показывается вкладка 1. Как запоминать положение вкладки и выводить после рефреша её?

Comment: Храните номер (или какой-то другой опознавательный знак) вкладки в localStorage. При каждом выборе (изменении) вкладки делаете: localStorage.setItem('tab', tab_number), а при загрузке странице берите это значение из localStorage: localStorage.getItem('tab')

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин, мне кажется, что лучше использовать не `localStorage`, а `sessionStorage`, реализация от этого не пострадает. Но это избавит от проблем, после повторного открытия браузера.